# Assume $X$ is compact, $Y$ locally compact Hausdorff, $\pi:X\times Y\to Y$ the projection map. Does $\pi$ map discrete subsets to discrete subsets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be compact Huasdorff, $Y$ locally compact Hausdorff, $\pi:X\times Y\to Y$ the projection map. Does $\pi$ map discrete subsets to discrete subsets?

I know that these conditions imply that $\pi$ is closed and proper.

Comment: Hint: Try to find a counter-example when $X=[0,1]$ and $Y={\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Let $X = Y = [0,1]$ and consider $S = \{(0, \frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{(1,0)\}$.

Comment: Yes, one can consider this subset and observe that it is not discrete. In fact, the claim holds if $Y$ is compact, as OP already noted.

Comment: Why is the subset not discrete? Which notion of discreteness are you using? I am using the definition that $S$ is discrete if and only if for every $x \in S$, there exists a neighbor $U$ of $x$ such that $U \cap S = \{x\}$.

Comment: No accumulation points. But you are right, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html